# When I try to start minecraft on Ubuntu 12.04 it says It requires a Java Runtime Enviroment 1.5.0

Tags: 12.04, updates, java

Please help!I want to play this game, I've been looking for a way to get this to work, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: What does the command: `java -version` show ?

Answer (score 2):

Open Terminal and Type Following Commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk* 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update <br>
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

This removes the OpenSource Java Runtime environment, and adds a software source. It then gets an update from these sources, and installs the official Runtime Environment 7 released by Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

oracle-java7-installer did not work for me.
I've successfully installed Oracle JRE following [HOWTO from EasyLinux Project](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/java)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Just a friendly heads up, but "link only" answers are something someone could find on google. So contribute to the community! Give a full answer, even if you have to copy and paste from the site. If you want, you can cite your sources.